# How to safely use a property on an object that has only been introducted into iOS recently?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I would like to use the **disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal** property on **UIViewController** that has been introduced into iOS 4.3 recently.

How do you handle/check for situations where the an earlier version of iOS is running my application and this property isn't available?

If it was a selector, I would use **respondsToSelector:@selector(something)** but I'm not sure what to do for a property.

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A property just declares setters and getters. In this case:

```
setDisablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal:
```

and

```
disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
```

So you can just do:

```
if([object respondsToSelector:@selector(disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal)]) {
    // do your stuff here    
}
```

Comment: Duh! Of course. Sorry, I was overthinking this! I'll accept the answer when stackoverflow allows me to in a few minutes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing @pt2ph8's answer, a property is little more than a fancy way to generate methods (the differences aren't important at this level). The existence of a readable property means that instances will respond to a selector of that name, and so `-respondsToSelector:` is the correct test.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Feel a bit foolish now for overthinking this one! My brain must be having a slow day!